# Magento 1.8 - Add New Category - SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock

Tags: magento-1.8

There is something wrong with the categories... whenever I try to add a new subcategory I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The `catalog_url_rewrite` index seems to be corrupt somehow.  It was stuck on processing and locked.  I deleted all lock files under `var/locks` which freed it back up.

I then set all indexes to manual rather than update on save.  However I am still getting the deadlock error.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to phpmyadmin and open `core_url_rewrite` table. You need to just truncate that table and go to index management and reindex all. The reindexing will take sometime, as URLs need to regenerate.

This will clear the table errors and the issue will get fixed.

Before doing this, **do take db/table backup**, just in case to revert back if you have done anything wrong.

You dont have to worry as reindexing will populate the table contents back.

Comment: Cheers buddy, this seems to have sorted the issues! Scary, but worked.

Comment: :) happy that you succeeded